# Yellow background on back of image On click

Tags: android, gridview

I am using GridView to show the gallery images. But when i click on any image, yellow color on back of image is coming. How can i remove it?

Here is the code i am using

```
<GridView
                android:id="@+id/party_gallery_gridview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/party_detail_layout_margin"
                android:listSelector="@null"
                android:numColumns="3"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/party_detail_layout_margin"
                android:visibility="gone" >
            </GridView>
```

You can see the yellow background in the below image

[image]

Comment: have u tried setting background of GRIDVIEW to TRANSPARENT ?

Comment: Please post the code for image: xml/code

Answer (score 1):

You can a new XML **bg_pressed.xml** in ***drawable directory***.

And it must contain `<selector>`  tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_pressed="true" >
            <shape>
                <solid
                    android:color="#000" />
    </shape>
    </selector>
```

and than

you can in Grid Cell

```
android:background="@drawable/bg_pressed.xml"
```

I hope ıt helps :)

Comment: Could you please take answer green arrow ? :)

Comment: How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to gridview

android:listSelector="#00000000"

Answer (score 0):

Try to make gridview background trasnparent, like this way :

```
  <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

Find your item view layout file and change its background to a corresponding background drawable.
Here is an example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/bb_drawerlayout_menu_item_height"
            android:background="@drawable/appkit_drawerlayout_menu_item_bg"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingEnd="12dp"
            android:paddingStart="0dp"
            tools:background="@color/black"
            tools:layout_width="240dp">
```

The content of `appkit_drawerlayout_menu_item_bg` is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/bbkit_black" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/bbkit_black" android:state_activated="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

Hope this makes sense to you.